# Which one is bigger (loglogn)! or (log(n!))?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, big-o

Need your help, stuck on this question:
determine the asymptotic relation between (log(log(n)))! and (log(n!))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the lemma that `log(n!) = Theta(n log(n))` (can be proved by Stirling approximation for `n!`).

Now, as the `log` function is increasing, you can take a `log` from these two functions, and finally compare them to find the relation:

```
# lemma: log(n*m) = log(n) + log(m)
log(log(n!)) = Theta(log(n) + log(log(n)) = Theta(log(n))

# using Stirling lemma
log(log(log(n))!) = Theta(log(log(n)) * log(log(log(n))))
```

As `log(log(n)) * log(log(log(n))) = o(log(n))` (can be proved by taking `log` from these two functions: reach to `log(log(log(n))` and `log(log(n))`.), hence, `log(log(n))! = o(log(n!)` (little-oh). In other words, `log(log(n))!` is asymptotically less than `log(n!)`.

Comment: Don't even need Stirling. Just bound `log(n!)` between the integral from `1` to `n` of `log(n)`, and the integral from `1` to `n+1` of `log(n)`.